# Searching for patterns in csv files

Tags: grep, perl, text-processing, csv

I have file.csv that looks like this

```
4,6,18,23,26
5,12,19,29,31
2,5,13,16,30
9,10,24,27,32
4,5,10,19,22
4,6,8,10,25
2,3,4,25,11
```

I want to find some patterns and save them in another log file  `file.log` and remove them from the first file. Perl or grep  ideally

- for instance, if x+1 = x2, in range of 3, remove the row and log its existence in another file and where it existed. So then `2,4,5,25,11` will be removed from `file.csv` and in  `file.log` I would find something like `row 7: 2,3,4,25,11 was removed from file.csv`. I'm trying to find sequences

Comment: Do you have a list of the pattern you want to find or do you want to machine learn the patterns?

Comment: Also, your title speaks about txt files, but your question about csv files.

Comment: CSV *is* text. I wouldn't give it too much thought, I think he just mean this is stuff that can be readily processed; not binary.

Comment: @don.joey i have  patterns i want to look for, if machine learning is complicated topic, i'll ask about it later, but for now i have my patterns. I edited the title

Comment: @Oli  yes true, i edited the title anyway

Comment: You mention grep and Perl, but I think `awk` will also be helpful as it has nice features for addressing columns.

Comment: How do you "have" the patterns? They're going to need to be tested against the data.

Comment: Can you add the patterns to your question?

Comment: @dan08 okay no problem, it would be nice to know how to do it with awk

Comment: @don.joey i mean `2,3,4` is a pattern in the 7th row where x2 = x+1, in range of 3, it's a numeric sequence, and that's what i want to find, is that your question?

Comment: @Oli i tried to explain in the  comment below, is that your question

Comment: Do you mean that the value of the third *field* should be one more than that of the second field?

Comment: So other examples would be `7,8,9,95131,32132` and `112,113,114,2,5`? Your use of `x2` is confusing. For you `x2` is a different variable name, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we interpret your requirement to mean that the value of the third field (column) should be one more than that of the second field (column), then with `awk` you can do things like

```
awk -F, '
$3==$2+1 {print "row "NR": "$0" was removed from "FILENAME > "file.log"; next}1
' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

which will create your `file.log` as specified and write the remaining lines to `newfile.csv`. You can rename `newfile.csv` to `file.csv` after to simulate deletion.

Comment: This is quite smart. I'm usually all over `awk` but this just plain didn't occur to me today. Might be good to show how you could chain multiple patterns (with some containing multiple conditions) together into one beast.

Comment: What's the 1 doing on the end?

Comment: The `1` is a shorthand way to make it print everything else to `newfile` (every line that's not skipped owing to the `next` evaluates as `1` i.e. `true`, thus invoking awk's default action - which is to print the line)

Comment: although i'm a python guy, thumbs up for awk! i shouldve accepted the perl solution since i asked for it originally, but one has to admit this is the most beautiful script here

Comment: There's something wrong, that script test if s3=s2+1.... but I want it to be tested until the third row. I mean if there's 3 consecutive numbers they should be removed not 2

Comment: You can add other logical conditions to the test e.g. `$2==$1+1 && $3==$2+1 {print ...`

Comment: @steeldriver I have similar problem. I need rows that having value greater than 36 in consecutive 7 columns . see my [data](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25783230/)

Answer (score 6):

I think you need a heavier programming language for this. Python is *my* language of choice so here's a simple script with a simple example of a test:

```
import sys

tests = [
    lambda a, b, c, d, e: a+1==b and b+1==c and c+1==d and d+1==e,
]

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(t(*map(int, line.split(','))) for t in tests):
            sys.stderr.write('Line removed: %s\n' % line)
            continue
        print line
```

That's obviously only a skeleton example of tests but it should be usable. Run normally it will output just the lines that don't match to STDOUT and the ones that do to STDERR. This makes it useful for redirecting into a new file.

Here it is in action:

```
$ python patterns.py <(echo -n 1,2,3,4,5)
Line removed: 1,2,3,4,5

$ python patterns.py <(echo -n 1,2,4,4,5)
1,2,4,4,5
```

Once you've loaded it up with patterns, you can just pass it the csv: `python patterns.py input.csv`

---

In terms of performance, Python isn't always the fastest. *I* use it because it's more than fast enough for web development and the time to write is much faster (which is what costs me time/money).

You can speed things up with PyPy. This is an alternative Python runtime that [benchmarks amazingly well](http://speed.pypy.org/). You might not need the PPA version (Trusty ships 2.2, PPA is 2.3.1) but here's how you would:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypy/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pypy
```

You'd then launch your script with `pypy script.py` or if you're executing it directly change the opening shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env pypy`. I've done some *very* simple testing on a 350000-line input file (your example [repeated 50000 times](https://askubuntu.com/q/521465/449)) with the above script.

`python2` ran it in 1.417s and `pypy` ran it in `0.645s`. In my experience, you're likely going to see an even bigger improvement with more complicated algos.

... But yeah, none of this is going to beat the C/C++ equivalent. If the time it takes to run is money, spend some time reimplementing it in a faster language.

Comment: can it be made faster? yesterday i was trying it on  a big file, it's taking too much time, compared to perl which does it in 3 seconds or so

Comment: Ordering your tests so the most likely is first will help, but you'll reach a point where Python does lag behind other languages... It's both slower and faster than Perl ([on different things](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/perl.php)). You could try Pypy which tends to be [much faster](http://speed.pypy.org/) than the default Python runtime... But if you want to do this seriously, you'll do the whole thing in C/C++  which at this level, it's that hard to do at all.

Answer (score 2):

perl:

```
$ perl -i.bak -F, -ane '
    if ($F[0]+1 == $F[1] and $F[1]+1 == $F[2]) {warn "row $.: $_"} else {print}
' file.csv 2>file.log
$ cat file.log
row 7: 2,3,4,25,11
$ cat file.csv
4,6,18,23,26
5,12,19,29,31
2,5,13,16,30
9,10,24,27,32
4,5,10,19,22
4,6,8,10,25
```

Comment: if i put it in script.pl it wont work, only in terminal