# Looping through csv, removing patterns

Tags: perl, awk, text-processing, haskell

I have  a question similar to my [earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508627/searching-for-patterns-in-csv-files), but a bit different

say you have 10 columns on each line, and 100000 lines, I want to check if each row for the following patterns:

If a  row looks like this, i want to remove it

```
 lambda a, b, c, d: a==a and a+1==b and b+1==c and c+1==d and d+1==e
```

While this solution works great, all solutions worked, all followed the same logic. The problem is that say i have 10 rows, That solution removes lines that have 5 consecutive numbers starting from a to e,

If the sequence starts from b to f, it will stay

I want a solution that is controlled by a loop so i won't have to keep adding and removing variables

I mean I want to remove all the sequences greater than 3, in the row,

I mean that if there are 3 consecutive numbers in the row, `a==a and a+1==b and b+1==c` leave them, if there are more than 3 consecutive numbers `a==a and a+1==b and b+1==c and c+1==d and so on` then remove them, wherever they may occur.

I mean it may be

```
a==a and a+1==b and b+1==c and c+1==d

a==a and a+1==a and b+1==c and c+1==d and d+1==e and e+1==f

and so on
```

So I'd rather to do it in a loop or similar solution, so I don't have to write all possibilities

Like last time, I'd prefer awk or perl for learning purposes, I was told by a friend  that haskell can do that easily but I didn't find  the solution in haskell, if that's true then I'm curious to know how.

Please note that I don't mind recursive solutions. I will edit my question to give input and output example in few hours, when I get back home

**EDIT**

example input

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,5,8,11,14,16,17,18,19
1,2,3,5,7,9,15,29,34
11,22,25,30,40,55,80,83,90
```

expected output

```
1,2,3,5,7,9,15,29,34
11,22,25,30,40,55,80,83,90
```

Reason: the third row, contains only 3 consecutive numbers, fourth row, contains no consecutive numbers. first two rows should be removed.

Comment: It's pretty unclear - can you give an example with a couple of lines input, and the output you like to get? Also, for what reason are you proposing to implement it with a loop? Is the loop in itself really important?

Comment: With "10 rows on each line", do you mean "10 columns on each line"?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel the loop isnt important, recursive would work too, I will edit my question to give example when Im back home in few hours, cant do much on the phone and will let u know. Yes I meant 10 columns, I will try to fix that from my phone now

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I edited my question to include examples, anything else just let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tested:

```
awk -F, '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF-3; i++) 
        if ($i+1==$(i+1) && $i+2==$(i+2) && $i+3==$(i+3))
            next
    print
}' file
```

Comment: ok thank you sir, i'll test your solution tomorrow, to see how it works, and i have edited my question to include examples,if my question was unclear

Comment: tested against your data and fixed.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll test it tomorrow and  let u know what happens

Comment: works perfectly - what is the  NF-3 doing exactly?

Comment: NF is an awk variable: it's the number of fields in the current record. So NF-3 is the 4th last field.

Comment: could u please edit the script to include something i forgot to talk about? say `1,2,3,5,6,7,8` i want it removed, i mean, if there's more than 2 sequences of 3 consecutive numbers in the row, i want it removed, like `5,6,7,9,10,11`

Comment: @glennjackman would you explain your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Perl: (reedited, after the examples were added to the question)

from commandline:

```
perl -F, -ane'my($a,$b)=$F[0];$b=$b>($l=$a++==$_?$l+1:0)?$b:$l for@F;print if $b>5' \
file.txt
```

if you want to change the file, use the `-i` flag for the command line version, or use the redirect operator of your shell (`>`, **do not** use it on the same file, because it will be truncated *before* it is read!).

Comment: ok thank you sir, i'll test your solution tomorrow, to see how it works, and i have edited my question to include examples,if my question was unclear

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question, I thought only the beginning was interesting.

Comment: No, in that case, the answers to my previous question would work fine, what was bad about those solutions is that they won't remove  all, sequences, I need to keep changing the script and run it again

Comment: edited, should work now. Maybe I'll write an explanation tomorrow, since the script changed completely.